# ruby script as a service on OSX 10.6.2

Tags: macos, services

I have a sinatra ruby script that I want to be running at all times.

Would it be the best to run it as a service? So I can restart it easily.

How can I install my script on OSX 10.6.2 as a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `launchd` and specify [the following](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) in your LaunchDaemon/LaunchAgent's configuration:

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<true/>
```

> This optional key is used to control whether your job is to be kept continuously running or to let demand and conditions control the invocation. The default is false and therefore only demand will start the job. The value may be set to true to unconditionally keep the job alive. [...]

---

To restart, I believe you can just `kill` it and it'll come back automatically.

Comment: I think you wanted that to be `<true/>`.

Comment: @BenAlpert <true/>